# Latest update to 20.04 - unrecoverable errors - ASPCI and UBSAN

Tags: updates, kubuntu

Unfortunately I got hit by a major update error yesterday. Over 200 packages were pushed for Kubuntu 22.04. It basically bricked my system GUI - but I could use GRUB and get to a console and save the data. Is there a way to turn off UBSAN until everyone is onboard with it?  Also, looking for any ideas how to deal with the new ASPCI issues.

Here are the two errors:

[image: PCI Errors]
#1 Notice the end warning about being in "emergency mode." The logfile(s) were enormous and no help. Maintenance mode gives you a prompt - but no help, so - it's -D which gets to error #2.

I have no idea how many of these errors went by - at least two screens full:
[image: UBSAN Errors]

```
UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /tmp/vbox.0/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:<range of numbers>:<range of numbers>
index <the numbers range 1-10> is out-of-range for type 'page *[1]'

UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvGip.c:<range of numbers>:<range of numbers>
index <the numbers range 1-10> is out-of-range for type 'SUPGIPCPU [1]'
```

Rebuilding the system to 22.04 (original release) from scratch went perfectly. I have 3 core tools that I installed - VS Code, Virtualbox, and Filezilla. As soon as I did the update (this time with no intermediate updates) - same problem - mostly. The GUI works sometimes. Now I can login, but it's a role of the dice to see if it works or locks up at the splash screen.

I'm afraid I'm going to have to give up on kubuntu / ubuntu. This type of issue making it into production is not a risk I can afford - especially since it apparently happened before.

UPDATE:
There is possibly a virtual box release that might address some of the UBSAN errors. I've asked over the the vbox community and v7.10.11 is going to be released soo and that may help with this. The pci error still has not resolved, but also appears to not have any material impact.

Comment: "Here are the two errors: ASPCI Errors #1 is ASPCI, which I had fixed before" No you did not. Those are hardware bugs the kernel started echo'ing to the display as of kernel 5.19. We can not fix those; only suppress. Nothing to worry about: we ALL have those.

Comment: @Rinzwind - I have an AMD Ryzen CPU (16 core) - I thought the iommu settings were for intel only?  However, AMD virtualization is enabled.

Comment: @Rinzwind - ref the "pci error" - as far as I can tell, all of my pci devices are working correctly.  3 M2 drives, and nvidia graphics.  Of course there is the MB IO, but no other errors reported or kernel panic. (Thank goodness) Syslog doesn't show anything. No idea what to do.

Comment: ah yes :D and indeed weird. Never had an AMD so I hope someone else will comment :)  -- removed them